# Check if page creation date is within the last 7 days with Eleventy and Nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, nunjucks, eleventy

I posted a few days ago about having a way to check for newly created posts, and I am making some headway in this but got a little stuck as shortcodes are still a bit new to me. This is the shortcodes that I created to get today's date from Luxon (then subtract by 7 days to get the last week's date) and then compare it with a date that is passed in. At the moment, I have to convert the data passed in as they are coming from a few pages.

this is the shortcode:

```
config.addShortcode("newlyAdded", function(date) { 

let lastWeek = DateTime.now().minus({days: 7}).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

let itemDate = DateTime.fromFormat(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd').toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

if(lastWeek <= itemDate) {
    return "
    <span class='my-label uk-margin-small-right uk-margin-small-top tag-featured'>
      <i class='fas fa-star margin-right-5'></i>Newly Added</span>
    "
}
});
```

then I am trying to use the shortcode in a macro:

```
{% newlyAdded post.data.date %}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
"Invalid DateTime" when used in a Nunjucks macro
```

I feel like the solution is probably quite simple and has to do with shortcode syntax or something like that which I am unaware of.

Any and all advice is very appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: "*I know you can't use JS in Nunjucks…*". You can't use **that** javascript anywhere. ;-)

Comment: Yes, but it's being statically generated and I'd prefer to do this through Nunjucks to help out with performance as it does not need to be rendered client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert each date into seconds (with `Date().getTime()`), then just check if the difference is greater than the number of milliseconds in 1 week (`1000 * 60 * 24 * 7`)

For example:

```js
const dateToCheck = new Date(2022, 1, 1, 0);

const diff = new Date().getTime() - new Date(dateToCheck).getTime();

const msInWeek = 1000 * 60 * 24 * 7;

const isOlderThenWeek = diff > msInWeek;

console.log(isOlderThenWeek);
```

Or in your example,

```
const env = nunjucks.configure();

env.addGlobal('isOlderThenWeek', (startDate) => {
    return ((new Date().getTime() - new Date(startDate).getTime()) / 1000) > 604800
});

{% if isOlderThenWeek(inputDate) %}
  This post was added in the last week
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That would be a great solution, the only issue is that you can't actually run native JS in Nunjucks so I am looking for a way to get the current date in Nunjucks or somehow in Eleventy that I can pass into the Nunjucks if statement

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, my mistake. I just saw the JavaScript tag, and totally missed the nunjucks requirement. Could you not still use JS, if you wrap it in `nunjucks.configure().addGlobal`?

Comment: Do you know if this option is possible in Eleventy?

Comment: You can just use normal JS with Eleventy, so yes it will work. Unless you mean using the content date?

Answer (score 0):

I guess proper solution is to schedule generation of your static site for once a day, to get this works.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding a solution, eleventy.js is currently a little buggy so you have to reload the server everytime you make a change and that was messing with me a bit. Anyway this is the shortcode:

```
config.addNunjucksShortcode("newlyAdded", function (date) {
        let today = DateTime.now().toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

        let lastWeek = DateTime.now().minus({
            days: 7
        }).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

        let itemDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd').plus({
            days: 1
        }).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

        if (lastWeek <= itemDate) {
            return `
            <span class='my-label tag-seo added'><i class='fas fa-star margin-right-5'></i>New This Week</span>
                `
        } else {
            return ``
        }

    });
```